# ensamblador RISC-V

Tags: ensamblador

hola necesito ayuda declarando una matriz con valores en punto flotante en lenguaje ensamblador RISC-v

```
float W[2][5]={0.4,0.75,1.2,6.8,7.2,1.1,0.9,2.2,1.5,0.78};
float A[2]={0.4,6.1};
float B[2];
```

Comment: Podrías leer su interpretación entera: `*(int*)&A[0]` y almacenarlo como un entero pero luego interpretarlo como `float`. No es la gran cosa, pero serviría.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero, la forma exacta de declarar las matrices puede variar dependiendo del ensamblador que estés utilizando y de la arquitectura RISC-v que estés programando. Este ejemplo se basa en la sintaxis de GNU Assembler (GAS) para RISC-v. Dicho lo cuál...

Para declarar matrices en lenguaje ensamblador RISC-v, necesitas utilizar la directiva .float para indicar que los valores serán de punto flotante.

Para declarar la matriz W con los valores proporcionados, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
.section .data
W:
  .float 0.4, 0.75, 1.2, 6.8, 7.2
  .float 1.1, 0.9, 2.2, 1.5, 0.78
```

En este caso, hemos creado una sección .data para almacenar la matriz W. La matriz tiene dos filas y cinco columnas, por lo que la hemos declarado como una matriz 2x5. Luego, utilizamos la directiva .float para declarar los valores de la matriz en orden de fila y columna.

Para el caso de las matrices unidimensionales, ambas son de 2 elementos, pero una no la inicializas, pero siempre le debes dar un valor, en este caso la he puesto a 0, pero la puedes inicializar con lo que quieras. Quedaría del siguiente modo:

```
.section .data
A:
  .float 0.4, 6.1
B:
  .float 0.0, 0.0
```

He empleado la directiva .data para almacenar estas matrices en la sección de datos.